# Redux form - how to set fields as touched

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm working with form that consists of multiple pages and I want to solve validation.

When I hit Submit button all fields on the present page shows error messages beneath, but if I change the page then I need to hit submit again because these fields weren't set as touched.

My problem would be solved if I could for example set all fields on the page as touched, once the form has flag `anyTouched: true`.

I'm using `redux-form: '^6.0.0-rc.4'` and I have one container where I include redux-form and multiple components consisting of fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I should have looked better:

Redux form returns touch as a prop to the component. The function takes names of fields as a parameter, so I'm checking in `componentWillUpdate` when `submitFailed` will change and then I'm gonna touch all fields that are not valid.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    const {
      formName: { syncErrors },
      submitFailed,
      touch
    } = this.props

    if (submitFailed !== nextProps.submitFailed) {
      const toTouch = []

      for (const key in syncErrors) {
        syncErrors.hasOwnProperty(key) && toTouch.push(key)
      }
      touch(...toTouch)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 18):

I think your problem was the opposite way around, but in case anyone lands here as I did looking for a way to have `anyTouched` set after any field in the form is touched...

In **redux-form 6 and above** you have to explicitly choose the behaviour you want with the form-level configurations `touchOnChange` and `touchOnBlur` - [see the docs here](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-touchonblur-boolean-code-optional-) - by default nothing is configured and so nothing happens.

```
const Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'my-form',
  touchOnChange: true,
  touchOnBlur: true
})(...)
```

These flags make it so that any given field is marked as touched (and therefore `anyTouched` is marked `true` on the form) when that field's `onChange` or `onBlur` handler is called, respectively.

Comment: ```touchOnChange: true``` ...gold

Answer (score 2):

In redux-form 7.4.2. This can be achieved by checking to see if the form is **valid**.

If valid you can can load one of your other pages. 
If the form is not valid, use reduxForms **getFormSyncErrors** selector and pass in the keys returned by this object to the reduxForm **touch** property.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, getFormSyncErrors } from 'redux-form';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  ...

  this.props.valid ? 
    // navigate away 
    : this.props.touch(...Object.keys(this.props.formErrors))

  ...

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    formErrors: getFormSyncErrors('myForm')(state)
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null),
  reduxForm({form: 'myForm'})
)(MyComponent)
```